# Filling an Empty DataTable gives SQL Exception "Invalid Column Name" -- Which Doesn't make sense?

Tags: c#, sql, exception

So I am trying to fill up an empty DataTable in C# using the various Sql helping classes which allow you to do so.  I am encountering an error now which says that the "Column Name A is invalid"... this doesn't make sense to me because the DataTable is EMPTY, and I am trying to fill it, not extract anything from any of its columns.

The first piece of data that I am pulling (from my SQL database) below has a SKUStockCode cell with 'A' in it, as seen in cmd2.  The DataTable is called containsAllRelatedProductData below.  However I am not trying to write this 'A' as a column in my new DataTable, I am only referencing 'A' because it is the SKUStockCode of the row I am trying to get data from in my SQL database.

```
    foreach(char ch in containsRelatedProductsStringOnly.Rows[0]["SKURelatedProducts"].ToString()) 
    {
         if(ch != ' ')
         {
             stockCode = stockCode + ch;
         }
         else
         {
             SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT SKUName FROM COM_SKU WHERE SKUStockCode = " + stockCode, con);
             SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
             adapter2.Fill(containsAllRelatedProductData); //Error
             stockCode = "";
         }
    }
```

I don't understand why the error would be Invalid Column Name, unless there are some naming restrictions on making new columns in a DataTable (which there are not that I know of).  Again the error comes on FILLing this empty DataTable (called containsAllRelatedProductData), not extracting anything from it.  Anyone have any idea why I would get an Invalid Column Name error?

Comment: Set the datatable column name and query column name are same !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command looks like:

```
SELECT SKUName FROM COM_SKU WHERE SKUStockCode = CODE0001
```

But it should be like that:

```
SELECT SKUName FROM COM_SKU WHERE SKUStockCode = 'CODE0001'
```

So you have to to encapsulate your input string with `'` as below

```
foreach(char ch in containsRelatedProductsStringOnly.Rows[0]["SKURelatedProducts"].ToString()) 
{
     if(ch != ' ')
     {
         stockCode = stockCode + ch;
     }
     else
     {
         SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT SKUName FROM COM_SKU WHERE SKUStockCode = '" + stockCode+"'", con);
         SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
         adapter2.Fill(containsAllRelatedProductData); //Error
         stockCode = "";
     }
}
```

Comment: So that appeared to work... I will have to investigate why, this is ridiculous I spent at least 2 hours on this program, which is so simple and it was because of syntax apparently.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
new SqlCommand("SELECT SKUName FROM COM_SKU WHERE SKUStockCode = '" + stockCode + "'", con);
```